# Persisting Entity Dropdownlist into database using Symfony2 & Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

ProductType.php

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('id_seller', 'text')
                ->add('tag', 'text')
                ->add('hot', 'checkbox', array(
                    'label' => 'Show this entry publicly?',
                    'required' => false))
                ->add('featured', 'checkbox')
                ->add('new', 'checkbox')
                ->add('shipping', 'checkbox')
                ->add('id_category', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'ProductBundle:ProductCategory',
                    'property' => 'name'
                        )
                )
                ->add('Add', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName() {

        return 'product';
    }

}
```

ProductRepository.php

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function addProduct($id_seller, $tag, $hot, $featured, $new, $shipping, $id_category, $username) {

        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $product = new Product();

        $product->setIdSeller($id_seller);
        $product->setTag($tag);
        $product->setHot($hot);
        $product->setFeatured($featured);
        $product->setNew($new);
        $product->setShipping($shipping);
        $product->setIdCategory($id_category);
        $product->setStatus('0');
        $product->setDateUpdate(new \Datetime($date));
        $product->setUpdatedBy($username);
        $product->setDateAdd(new \Datetime($date));

        $em = $this->_em;
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        return true;
    }

}
```

The controller:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/add")
     *
     */
    public function addProductAction(){

        $product = new Product();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);

        $request = $this->get('request');
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($request->getMethod() == "POST"){

            if($form->isValid()){

                $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
                $username = $user->getUsername();

                $id_seller = $form->get('id_seller')->getData();
                $tag = $form->get('tag')->getData();
                $hot = $form->get('hot')->getData();
                $featured = $form->get('featured')->getData();
                $new = $form->get('featured')->getData();
                $shipping = $form->get('shipping')->getData();
                $id_category = $form->get('id_category')->getData();

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $product = $em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product')->addProduct($id_seller, $tag, $hot, $featured, $new, $shipping, $id_category, $username);
            }
        }

        return $this->render('ProductBundle:Product:addproduct.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView()));
    }
}
```

Error code:
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Product (id_seller, tag, hot, featured, new, shipping, id_category, status, date_update, updated_by, date_add) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["123", "123", 1, 1, 1, 0, {}, "0", "2014-11-21 10:59:06", "admin", "2014-11-21 10:59:06"]:

Can I know how to get the value for the id_category dropdownlist? As i'm getting "{}" as you can see from the error message. The values should either be 1,2,3 or 4.

Thanks alot.

Comment: It has entity Type. Have you tried doing $product->setIdCategory( $id_category->getId() );

Comment: Is there a reason you don't check if the form is sent and call `set...()` for each field? Please check the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions), you'll find how to do the same thing with less code.

Comment: I just noticed you persist the entity in the Entity Repository. That's not a common practice in Symfony2. You should do this from the Controller. Please show the complete code, we don't see how `ProductType` is used in your current code.

Comment: How do you pass arguemtns to `addProduct` method? Can you show it?  Looks like error is in it.. `Entity` field type should work fine if you do everything properly.

Comment: Also, you say categoryId should return `1,2,3 or 4`, but you're setting `'property' => 'name'`, is it ok?

Comment: @A.L I've updated the code including the controller, isn't the repository meant for doing queries and stuffs? Like a modal?

Comment: @xurshid29 The 'property'=>'name' makes the dropdownlist displays the name of the category but the value is using the id of the category when i checked the html codes. Is this correct?

Comment: ah, yes. I'm confused.

Comment: You don't need to call all the setters, please look the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#forms-and-doctrine), it's very easy to persist an entity!

Comment: Ok i've done that but the entity field still getting a {}. Am i getting the entity field data correctly?